# What's a word for someone who makes clockwork mechanisms?

Tags: word-request

I know the word horologist, but that seems to be for actual clocks. I don't know if it's the correct word, or if there's a more specific one.

Comment: I think there are no "synonyms" for ***clockwork*** in the sense of *mechanism with a spring and toothed gearwheels*. So there probably won't be any alternatives to ***clockmaker***  that don't imply making ***timepieces*** (as opposed to toy clockwork cars, etc.). But ***modelmaker*** might come close, with the right context.

Comment: [*Wind-up toymaker?*](https://www.mainstreetreps.com/Default.aspx?tabid=203&manuid=33)

Comment: Clock mechanician?

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think there is one word for this. What about a maker/manufacturer of clockwork mechanisms?  I suppose you could make those into a compound noun: a clockwork mechanism manufacturer/maker.

Comment: Is there a word in your native language for such a profession or hobby?

Comment: You have a choice of general or specific: *machinist* or *toymaker*, *watchmaker*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** If you mean someone who makes something *other than* the mechanical assembly which runs a clock, none of my answers will apply. *All of what follows is about people who are involved with clock and watch mechanisms.*

**Horology**: the study of timekeeping, is the overall category of engineering concerning **measuring time**. It is a specialized term, most native English speakers wouldn't use it in ordinary discourse. *George is a horologist, a physicist who works with the United States atomic clock*.

**Clockmaker, Watchmaker (1):** Since it is very unusual for an individual to manufacture entire clocks or watches, these terms are both widely used to describe people who **repair clocks and watches**. *Irene is a watchmaker who leases space from the jewelry store to repair watches*.

**Clockmaker, Watchmaker (2):** These refer collectively to the **companies which manufacture timepieces**. *Rolex is a Swiss watchmaker which produces approximately 800,000 watches per year*. The employees of such companies who do the actual work may also be referred to as *watchmakers*. *Ruth is a watchmaker who assembles winding mechanisms at Rolex, S.A. in Geneva.*